# MUMPS doesn't permit to create a file bigger than 2 GB

Tags: mumps

We know that MUMPS does not allow to create files bigger than 2 GB.

A Volume Group accepts 16GB, but only with 2 GB for each VG file.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the OS your implementation of MUMPS DB is installed on, in particular check the user setup (user's *ulimit* in case of Unix) I don't want to guess around since you did not specify any details about your implementation (M DB type and version, OS type and version).

MUMPS definitely allows to create files greater than 2GB. MUMPS Database region files are usually way over 20GB, MUMPS Database Journal Files are kept at 2GB for ease of maintenance, but could be greater, output files MUMPS system at hand may produce (in a batch on demand) can grow to whatever size the file system allows it.

Comment: Andre, 

Thank you very much for your response.
It is very difficult to find help on this subject.

If you are referring to the unix fsize parameter, I believe it is configured correctly in my / etc / security files

root:
   Fsize_hard = -1
   Fsize = -1

Do I need to set some configuration somewhere else?